# How to implement backpack UI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I want to make a backpack UI that can dynamically add and delete items like a menu, but every item in it is a picture (not a text)

[image: 1]

I found many tutorials but all of them are panels with slots that need I to set their positions previously. I wonder if there is a better way to make it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a Vertical Layout Group:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html

Obviously for adding and deleting in player, you have to create buttons with relative scripts.